# Run shell script inside Docker container from another Docker container?

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, docker

If I am on my host machine, I can kickoff a script inside a Docker container using:

`docker exec my_container bash myscript.sh`

However, let's say I want to run `myscript.sh` inside `my_container` from another container `bob`. If I run the command above while I'm in the shell of `bob`, it doesn't work (Docker isn't even installed in `bob`).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: yes, bind mounting the docker socket is an easy way to do so

Comment: @user2915097 unfortunately I posted too quickly - when I bind mount and run `docker exec ...` it gives me `cannot connect to the Docker daemon` error. Is there something else I need to do in addition to the socket mount?

Comment: do you launch your container with `docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` and so ?

Comment: @user2915097 Thank you- Launching the container with both `-v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` and `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` works! If you make your comment into an answer, I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply launch your container with something like

`docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` ...

and it should do the trick